# TYPO3: How to get a domain property field with type ObjectStorage<SomeSubType> mapped from a fluid form in extbase?

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

Does someone know how to get a domain property field with type ObjectStorage mapped from a fluid form in extbase on TYPO3 10LTS?

I've got the following property in the domain object:

```
    /**
     * @var ObjectStorage<Employee>|null
     */
    protected ?ObjectStorage $companyEmployees = null;
```

And this is one field of the fluid template:

```
<f:form.textfield property="companyEmployees.0.firstName" id="companyEmployees.0.firstName" additionalAttributes="{required: 'required'}"/>
```

`firstName` is one property of the `Employee` domain object.

I would expect to get an ObjectStorage filled with one `Employee` object filled with the `firstName`. But I'm getting the following exception:

```
Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: Return value of TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Property\TypeConverter\ObjectStorageConverter::getTypeOfChildProperty() must be of the type string, null returned
```

Any ideas on how to do it correctly?

Comment: Do you always need only the first object in this storage? Or why do you use an object when you need to edit only one?

Comment: Nope I have multiple of them. So I do indeed need an Object Storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the answer to that question is pretty simple. The object mapper of extbase does try to find out the correct type for each property of the object. The first way of doing that is by trying to find the setter method of the property. In my case this would be the `setCompanyEmployees`.

And this one has to be build in the following way:

```
    /**
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\MyVendor\Ext\Domain\Model\Employee> $companyEmployees
     */
    public function setCompanyEmployees($companyEmployees): void
    {
        $this->companyEmployees = $companyEmployees;
    }
```

It is important to note that you **have** to use the FQN in the PHPdoc @param notation. In other parts of extbase it is no longer necessary to use the FQN since 10LTS but here it is!

Secondly it is important to note that you **have** to omit the type of the parameter. So in my case I had `public function setCompanyEmployees(ObjectStorage $companyEmployees)` which did not work since you can't have a subtype in PHP (there is nothing like `ObjectStorage<Employee>`) and extbase prefers the parameter type over the phpdoc @param notation. And that leads to the error mentioned in the question since the parameter type would be `ObjectStorage` without the subtype.

So to sum up use `public function setCompanyEmployees($companyEmployees)` and the FQN in the @param notation and the mapping does work perfectly in Typo3 10LTS.

Comment: The strange thing is: I have to do exactly the same (using FQCNs in setter PHPdoc) in one project (10 LTS). But in another project (10 LTS, too), I can completely remove the FQCNs and use imports. There I had to add "ObjectStorage" to the setters method signature... I don't know why one project behaves different than another.